# My hr block is not showing up where I want it to

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to make a help screen that pulls up an html file using an android webview that shows a list of icons and gives a description for each.  I would like to put an **hr** tag between each icon/description row.

My code looks like this:

```
<div>
<img src=[link] align="left"/>
<p> [Description] </p>
</div>
<hr>
```

The problem is that if the image is taller than the description, the hr block runs into the image and stops, instead of being below the tallest element, and spanning the entire width.  Is there a way to tell the hr block to come below the bottom of the lowest element in the div?

Thanks in advance

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid at all to begin with.  Second, we need to see the whole thing, CSS included, to help you.

Comment: Do you have a CSS file that could make some effect on that, like with `float` parameter?

Comment: There is no CSS that goes with it.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your CSS;

```
hr { clear: both; }
```

If there is no CSS then I'm lost. If the div isn't being floated, or none of the other elements are floated, I don't see how your problem could occur.
Try adding the following CSS;

```
<hr style="float:left;width:100%;clear:both">
```

Comment: no luck unfortunately.  I am using an android webview to interpret this html if that is of any help

Comment: Could you post your CSS please?

Comment: There isn't any css.  It's just an html file

Comment: I've updated my answer for you to try one more thing
If that doesn't work then I have no clue I'm afraid.

Comment: I was really hoping that would work, but it did not.  I updated the original post with a graphic in hopes that it could shed some light on an idea, although I think you already knew what I was talking about.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  I messed around with your hr line and got it to work.  I edited your post to remove the clear, because for some reason that caused weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be an issue with block display; particularly if this is occurring in IE, you may need to update your div's style so it's rendered as expected.

If it's IE-only, google hasLayout.  Otherwise, as has been said, post your CSS.

Comment: there's no css to go with it, it's just a basic html file that I have an android webview reading